# What is most elegant way to clip a string between words, after n characters?

Tags: php, substring

Given a string, what is the best way to generate a substring after n characters, without breaking up words?

Example:

```
$str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum."
echo summary($str,100); // i.e. summary($string,$numberOfCharacters);
```

Should result in:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tindunt laoreet...
```

Comment: using regex is the easiest way

Comment: or even simpler is to use strpos and check if the last character is a lett\er

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function summary($str,$len)
{
    return trim(preg_replace("/^(.{0,$len})\\s.*/","\\1",$str.' '));
}
```

This takes 0..$len chars up to a space, and returns that. Example:

```
$str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.";

for ( $i=20;$i<30;$i++ ) echo summary($str,$i)."\n";
```

outputs:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor
Lorem ipsum dolor sit
Lorem ipsum dolor sit
Lorem ipsum dolor sit
Lorem ipsum dolor sit
Lorem ipsum dolor sit
Lorem ipsum dolor sit
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
```

Edit: You might want to `trim()` the output, to remove spaces.

Edit2: strings shorter then $len would have a word chopped off, added a space to prevent that. (quick&dirty)

PS. You may want to replace `\\s` with whatever you think a suitable non-word pattern is. I'd suggest `[^a-zA-Z]`.

Answer (score 1):

This might help you:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php#99828

```
function cutstr($str, $length, $ellipsis=''){
   $cut=(array)explode('\n\n',wordwrap($str),$length,'\n\n'));
   return $cut[0].((strlen($cut)<strlen($str))?$ellipsis:'');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple and elegant implementation.
Adapted from http://code.web-max.ca/truncate_string.php

```
<?php
function summary($details,$max)
{
    if(strlen($details)>$max)
    {
        $details = substr($details,0,$max);
        $i = strrpos($details," ");
        $details = substr($details,0,$i);
        $details = $details."...";
    }
    return $details;
}

$str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.";

echo summary($str,100); // i.e. summary($string,$numberOfCharacters);

?>
```

If you prefer a more object oriented approach, I wrote the following class a few years back. It could use some enhancements, but it gets the job done. It has the added benefit of stripping HTML tags and you can choose something different than the standard ... for a trail string.

```
<?php
/**
 * Example:
 * $text = "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur <em>adipiscing</em> elit. Etiam tortor
 * justo, elementum non sollicitudin id, pharetra sit amet dolor. Sed porta mollis mauris,
 * vitae blandit nunc volutpat ac. In eros lorem, faucibus non commodo vel, vulputate ac
 * mauris.</p>";
 *
 * $short = new ShortText($text);
 * $short->ellipsesString = '&raquo;';
 * echo $short->trimTo(60),"\n\n";
 *
 * Result:
 * Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.»
 */
class ShortText
{
    public $ellipses;
    public $stripHtml;
    public $ellipsesString;

    private $text;

    public function __construct($text)
    {
        $this->ellipses = true;
        $this->stripHtml = true;
        $this->ellipsesString = '...';
        $this->text = $text;
    }

    /**
     * trims text to a space then adds ellipses if desired
     * @param string $input text to trim
     * @param int $length in characters to trim to
     * @param bool $ellipses if ellipses (...) are to be added
     * @param bool $strip_html if html tags are to be stripped
     * @return string 
     */
    public function trimTo($length)
    {
        $input = $this->text;

        //strip tags, if desired
        if ($this->stripHtml) {
            $input = strip_tags($input);
        }

        //no need to trim, already shorter than trim length
        if (strlen($input) <= $length) {
            return $input;
        }

        //find last space within length
        $last_space = strrpos(substr($input, 0, $length), ' ');
        $trimmed_text = substr($input, 0, $last_space);

        //add ellipses (...)
        if ($this->ellipses) {
            $trimmed_text .= $this->ellipsesString;
        }

        return $trimmed_text;
    }
}

$str = "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.</p>";

$short = new ShortText($str);
echo $short->trimTo(100),"\n\n";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This Perl Regex should do it

> /^(.*){100}/

Answer (score 0):

```
function summary($string, $length)
{
    return ($offset = @stripos($string, ' ', $length) !== FALSE) ?
        substr($string, 0, ($length + $offset)) . '...' : $string;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the PHP **substr**  function to get the substring of the single word or statement

For example.

```
echo substr($str,0,100);
```

For your reference you can use the following link.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Comment: That doesn't answer the question, it just cuts the string at a fixed point, space or not.